# One in four values not passing in function

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I tried to pass 4 values in a function, but the fourth value seem like not passed and always zero. Here are my code:

```
Sub romberg()
'
' romberg Macro
' 3 Sep 2013

'
Dim x0 As Long
Dim fx As Long
Dim x1 As Long
Dim stepsize As Long
Dim J, K, c As Long

Range("A12:N65536").Clear
Columns("A:N").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
'column i
'J=0
x0 = Cells(9, 2)
fx = Cells(9, 3)
x1 = Cells(9, 4)
stepsize = Cells(9, 5)
Cells(13, 4) = t(x0, fx, x1, stepsize)
.
.
.
end sub

Public Function t(a As Long, f As Long, b As Long, h As Long)

Dim J As Integer

Sheets("T").Activate

Range("A8:D65536").Clear
Columns("A:D").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Cells(3, 1) = a
Cells(3, 2) = f
Cells(3, 3) = b
Cells(3, 4) = h
.
.
.
t = Cells(3, 6)
End Function
```

Comment: I only changed the way this code displays, were your commented out parts intended? those lines that contain 'column i and 'J=0. You have checked there is a value in h? what is J used for?

Comment: Have you made sure you have a value in the Row 3, Column 4? Is that the problem part?

Answer (score 0):

You indicated stepsize is a type of long while you are trying to pass a type cell.

Change this code

```
stepsize = Cells(9, 5)
Cells(13, 4) = t(x0, fx, x1, stepsize)
```

to

```
stepsize = Cells(9, 5).value
Cells(13, 4).value = t(x0, fx, x1, stepsize)
```